# How to make sure send `req` after query database?

Tags: express, mongoose

after receiving `req` from a client, the server will query mongodb and then send `res`,

```
var Article = mongoose.model('articles', articleSchema);

app.get('/api/topic',function(req,res){

    Article.find({"articleID":1},function(err,doc){
         res.json(doc)
    })

   res.send("the message that I don't want to send")
}
```

but `Model.find(query, fields, options, callback)` is an async method.
`res.json(doc)` does not work.

How to to make sure `res` send `doc`?

Comment: if you don't want to send the last message, simply remove the line. The server will respond once the query is completed

Comment: before `res.json` check `if(doc.length === 0)  res.send("the message that I don't want to send")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using ES6? You can use es6 or other Promises, as Article.find returns a new Promise for you.

```
Article.find(...).then((doc) => res.json(doc))
                 .catch((err) => { // error handling });
```

If you dont want to do the res.send inside the catch-block you could also declare your method as async and then use the await command to make your call sync. like so:

```
app.get('/api/topic', async function(req,res){

    await Article.find({"articleID":1},function(err,doc){
         res.json(doc)
    })

   res.send("the message that I don't want to send")
}
```

However we do not really know why you need the second res in the first place, so there might be other solutions which would be a better fit for your needs. Note the async await are also part of the ES6 Superset.

Here you can get more information about async/await

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

if you are not using ES6 but ES5 for some reason you could also just use the npm module for promises or async/await.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promise

https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-async

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be sending a res outside the asynchronous function.  Try the code below which handles errors and additionally checks if the find was empty.

```
var Article = mongoose.model('articles', articleSchema);

app.get('/api/topic',function(req,res){

    Article.find({"articleID":1},function(err,doc){
         if(err)
           res.send(err);

         if(doc.length === 0)
           res.send(`No records found.`);
         else
           res.json(data);
    })
}
```

Comment: I have tried it, the server will send nothing back.